# Symfony undifined CreateForm method

Tags: forms, doctrine, symfony-forms

i want to generate a form to add a medicament but he don't recognize the method

**Controller**

```
$public function addAction (Request $Request)
{
    $Medicament = new Medicament();

    $form = $this->
    createForm(ModeleType::class,$Medicament);
    $form->handleRequest($Request);
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($Medicament);

        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
            'Pharmacie_Medicament_Add'
        ));

    }
```

**Form**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom')->add('quantite')->add('datePeremption')->add('prix')
    ->add('save',SubmitType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'PharmacieCentraleBundle\Entity\Medicament'
    ));
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'pharmaciecentralebundle_medicament';
}
```

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createForm" of class `PharmacieCentraleBundle\Controller\MedicamentController`

ignore this : kjetrzejkbfckzejvbkejvbkarebvnreblheabv eafvkljbeamjkvbelvbvbelvblb ealvberavhrve

Comment: i didnt extend Controller in my MedicamentController -_- ..

Answer (score 1):

In `createForm` function arguments, you need to pass an instance of `MedicamentType`, not `Medicament`

Reference: http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createForm